# padding display objects in a table corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Im having some issues with creating a level style selection page in Corona SDK. Im making an advent calendar style app and I want to create a calendar page where each day the user can select a day and it will open playing some xmas music, a sprite, etc.

My problem is that I cant seem to add padding between the day icons on the calendar (there all very bunched up).

Any help regarding this issue would be great! Thanks

(My code can be found below)

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()


-- local forward references should go here --

--levelProgress = 0
--levelImg = {}
--allLevels = {}


levels = 
{   
1,  2, 2, 2 , 2,  --1 means level is open to    be played (level.png)
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,   --2 means level is locked (locked.png)
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
-- 3 means level is completed (greenchecked.png)
}

images ={
       -- {topPaddig = 50},
    { getFile = "gift.png", types = "play", bottomPadding = 50   },
    { getFile = "lock.png", types = "locked", bottomPaddingPadding = 50},
    { getFile = "greenchecked.png", types = "done", bottomPadding = 50}
}


local function buttonHit(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene ( event.target.destination, {effect = "slideUp"} ) 
    print( event.target.destination)
        return true
end

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    local levelIndex =0
        for i=0,4 do
            for j=1,5 do
                tablePlace =   i*5 + j  
                levelIndex = levelIndex + 1
                    local imagesId = levels[levelIndex] 
                        levelImg = display.newImageRect (images[imagesId].getFile , 50, 50 )
                        levelImg.x = 0 + (j*55)
                        levelImg.y  = 130+ (i*55)
                        group:insert(levelImg)

                        leveltxt = display.newText("Day "..tostring(tablePlace), 0,0, "Helvetica", 10)
                        leveltxt.x = 0 + (j*55)
                        leveltxt .y = 155+ (i*55)
                        leveltxt:setTextColor (250, 255, 251)
                        group:insert (leveltxt)

                        levelImg.destination = "level0"..tostring(tablePlace)

                        if images[imagesId].types ~= "locked" then
                        levelImg:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
                        end
 end

end




    -- CREATE display objects and add them to 'group' here.
    -- Example use-case: Restore 'group' from previously saved state.

    local title = display.newText( "Level Selection", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 20 )
    title.x = centerX
    title.y = display.screenOriginY + 40
    group:insert(title)

    local backBtn = display.newText(  "Back", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 20 )
    backBtn.x = display.screenOriginX + 50
    backBtn.y = display.contentHeight  - 30 
    backBtn.destination = "menu" 
    backBtn:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
    group:insert(backBtn)



end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. start timers, load audio, start listeners, etc.)

end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listeners, unload sounds, etc.)
    -- Remove listeners attached to the Runtime, timers, transitions, audio tracks

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. remove listeners, widgets, save state, etc.)
    -- Remove listeners attached to the Runtime, timers, transitions, audio tracks

end



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: @Frozire No, that isn't how lua works -> http://codepad.org/aGUzRrwB

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting referencing the anchor point of each obejects? `object.anchorX = 0.5; object.anchorY = 0.5` [read here for more](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/15/tutorial-anchor-points-in-graphics-2-0/)

Comment: No, I had'nt thought of that, I'll give it a go thanks!